# BeanUtils not works for chain setter

Tags: java, reflection, chaining, apache-commons-beanutils, lombok

e.g.

```
class tester
{
    @Test
    public void testBeanUtils() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException
    {
        Stranger stranger = new Stranger();
        BeanUtils.setProperty(stranger,"name","wener");
        BeanUtils.setProperty(stranger,"xname","xwener");
        BeanUtils.setProperty(stranger,"yname","ywener");

        System.out.println(stranger);
    }
    @Data// lombok annotation generate all setter and getter
    public static class Stranger
    {
        @Accessors(chain = true)// generate chained setter
        String name;
        String xname;
        String yname;

        public Stranger setYname(String yname)// no lombok, still not work
        {
            this.yname = yname;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

```
TestValues.Stranger(name=null, xname=xwener, yname=null)
```

What's wrong with this? chain setter is a good thing.
Any suggests ?

**EDIT**

Back to this problem again.This time I can not remove the `Accessors chain`.
Now, I use the `commons-lang3` to achieve.

```
// force access = true is required
Field field = FieldUtils.getField(bean.getClass(), attrName, true);
field.set(bean,value);
```

For those who got the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's simple: `BeanUtils` are rather strange and so is `Introspector` it uses:

Although [`BeanUtils.setProperty`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.java#453) declares some exceptions, it seems to [silently ignore](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.java#906) the non-existence of the property to be set. The ultimate culprit is the `Introspector` which simply [requires](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/beans/Introspector.java#577) the voidness of setter.

I'd call it broken by design, but YMMV. It's an old class and fluent interfaces weren't invented yet in those dark times. Use [`Accessors(chain=false)`](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors.html) to disable chaining.

---

More important: [Use the source](http://www.bezdelnique.ru/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/use_source_luke.png). Get it and get a debugger (it's already in your IDE) to find it out yourself (still feel free to ask if it doesn't work, just try a bit harder).

Comment: Maybe BeanHelper can be used here. It seems to use a Fluent interface INstrospector. https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-configuration/+/b5ef1eb1a7dd34a06cf68dae4bfcada9e1121818/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/configuration/beanutils/BeanHelper.java

Comment: Tanks, Already disabled the chain, waiting for [BeanUtils2](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-beanutils2/)

Answer (score 23):

You can use the **FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector** implementation:

"An implementation of the BeanIntrospector interface which can detect write methods for properties used in fluent API scenario."

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector.html

```
PropertyUtils.addBeanIntrospector(new FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector());
BeanUtils.setProperty( this.o, "property", "value" );
```

Comment: This should be the solution. It actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my project we use chained accessors across the board, so setting `chain=false` was not an option. I ended up writing my own introspector, which is similar to the one recommended by @mthielcke, and may be registered in the same way.

**Introspector**

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanIntrospector;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.IntrospectionContext;

import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

/**
 * Allows {@link org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils#copyProperties(Object, Object)} to copy properties across beans whose
 * properties have been made <b>fluent</b> through <a href="https://projectlombok.org/">Lombok</a>
 * {@link lombok.experimental.Accessors}, {@link lombok.Setter} and {@link lombok.Getter} annotations.
 *
 * @author izilotti
 */
@Slf4j
public class LombokPropertyBeanIntrospector implements BeanIntrospector {

    /**
     * Performs introspection. This method scans the current class's methods for property write and read methods which have been
     * created by the <a href="https://projectlombok.org/">Lombok</a> annotations.
     *
     * @param context The introspection context.
     */
    @Override
    public void introspect(final IntrospectionContext context) {
        getLombokMethods(context).forEach((propertyName, methods) -> {
            if (methods[0] != null && methods[1] != null) {
                final PropertyDescriptor pd = context.getPropertyDescriptor(propertyName);
                try {
                    if (pd == null) {
                        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, methods[1], methods[0]);
                        context.addPropertyDescriptor(descriptor);
                    }
                } catch (final IntrospectionException e) {
                    log.error("Error creating PropertyDescriptor for {}. Ignoring this property.", propertyName, e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Map<String, Method[]> getLombokMethods(IntrospectionContext context) {
        Map<String, Method[]> lombokPropertyMethods = new HashMap<>(); // property name, write, read
        Stream.of(context.getTargetClass().getMethods())
                .filter(this::isNotJavaBeanMethod)
                .forEach(method -> {
                    if (method.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(context.getTargetClass()) && method.getParameterCount() == 1) {
                        log.debug("Found mutator {} with parameter {}", method.getName(), method.getParameters()[0].getName());
                        final String propertyName = propertyName(method);
                        addWriteMethod(lombokPropertyMethods, propertyName, method);
                    } else if (!method.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE) && method.getParameterCount() == 0) {
                        log.debug("Found accessor {} with no parameter", method.getName());
                        final String propertyName = propertyName(method);
                        addReadMethod(lombokPropertyMethods, propertyName, method);
                    }
                });
        return lombokPropertyMethods;
    }

    private void addReadMethod(Map<String, Method[]> lombokPropertyMethods, String propertyName, Method readMethod) {
        if (!lombokPropertyMethods.containsKey(propertyName)) {
            Method[] writeAndRead = new Method[2];
            lombokPropertyMethods.put(propertyName, writeAndRead);
        }
        lombokPropertyMethods.get(propertyName)[1] = readMethod;
    }

    private void addWriteMethod(Map<String, Method[]> lombokPropertyMethods, String propertyName, Method writeMethod) {
        if (!lombokPropertyMethods.containsKey(propertyName)) {
            Method[] writeAndRead = new Method[2];
            lombokPropertyMethods.put(propertyName, writeAndRead);
        }
        lombokPropertyMethods.get(propertyName)[0] = writeMethod;
    }

    private String propertyName(final Method method) {
        final String methodName = method.getName();
        return (methodName.length() > 1) ? Introspector.decapitalize(methodName) : methodName.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    private boolean isNotJavaBeanMethod(Method method) {
        return !isGetter(method) || isSetter(method);
    }

    private boolean isGetter(Method method) {
        if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers()) && method.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
            if (method.getName().matches("^get[A-Z].*") && !method.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)) {
                return true;
            }
            return method.getName().matches("^is[A-Z].*") && method.getReturnType().equals(Boolean.TYPE);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isSetter(Method method) {
        return Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())
                && method.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)
                && method.getParameterTypes().length == 1
                && method.getName().matches("^set[A-Z].*");
    }

}
```

**Registration**

```
PropertyUtils.addBeanIntrospector(new LombokPropertyBeanIntrospector());
BeanUtils.copyProperties(dest, origin);
```